# Find a string in list of lists

Tags: java, arrays

I have more than 15 lists of strings, each list contains several different codes. Each list contains codes of one specific type.
I have one input code and have to find out which list that input code belongs to and return one specific String based on the result. I have used if, else if to do that. Below is sample code

```
private static String getCodeType(String inputCode) {

    if (MyClass.getCodeTypeOneList().contains(inputCode)) {
        return "CodeType_A";
    } else if (MyClass.getCodeTypeTwoList().contains(inputCode)) {
        return "CodeType_B";
    } else if (MyClass.getCodeTypeThreeList().contains(inputCode)) {
        return "CodeType_C";
    } else if (MyClass.getCodeTypeFourList().contains(inputCode)) {
        return "CodeType_D";
    } else if (MyClass.getCodeTypeFiveList().contains(inputCode)) {
        "CodeType_E;
    } else if (MyClass.getCodeTypeixList().contains(inputCode)) {
        return "CodeType_F";
    } else if (MyClass.getWithDrawalCodeTypeList().contains(inputCode)) {
        return "CodeType_G";
    } 
     // similar 10 more if conditions
     else {
        return null;
     }
  }
```

Each List is like below:
public static List codeTypeOneList = new ArrayList();

```
public static final List<String> getCodeTypeOneList() {

    codeTypeOneList.add("AFLS");
    codeTypeOneList.add("EAFP");
    codeTypeOneList.add("ZDTC");
    codeTypeOneList.add("ZFTC");
    codeTypeOneList.add("ATCO");
    return codeTypeOneList;
}
```

(similar list for other code types)

is there any better way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You could use java 8 streams and flatten it to one list.

Comment: We're using java 7, can't use java 8

Answer (score 0):

As a one-time step, build a map:

```
Map<String, String> codeTypeMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String key : getCodeTypeOneList()) {
  codeTypeMap.put(key, "CodeType_A");
}
for (String key : getCodeTypeTwoList()) {
  codeTypeMap.put(key, "CodeType_B");
}
// ...
```

(You need to make sure either that no list element occurs in multiple lists; or to add them in order of reverse preference so that later code types overwrite earlier ones).

Then just use `codeTypeMap.get` to look up the type for the given code.

```
private static String getCodeType(String inputCode) {
  return codeTypeMap.get(inputCode);
}
```

Comment: HashMap doesn't allow duplicate key. Adding different key will over ride the previous code.

Comment: Indeed. But your current code *also* doesn't allow duplicate keys: it will always return the first matched. This is exactly the point I'm making in the "(You need to ...)" paragraph.

Comment: How could I retrieve the type of code if the key is already over ridden? What I mean to say is, suppose CodeTypeOneList contains 5 different codes, when I add them in map, key would be the last code entered. While retrieving the code, input could be any one of the code out of all possible codes.

Comment: but these "ZDTC" etc, are the keys.  and that is the key to the hashmap. so in the hashmap ZDTC returns CodeType_A.

it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve that this solution wouldn't achieve. you have for example ZDTC and want to return CodeType_A for it. in fact, your lists are completely unnecessary for the whole thing as well as you could just put("ZDTC","Codetype_A"); etc in one list and have a lot less code to muck around with, so I assume you need to clarify the question. in your example solution as well it cannot have two different codetypes returned for ZDTC.